# Rust bindgen ignore include specific include from header file

Tags: rust, clang, rust-bindgen

I have a header file lets say greetings.h:

```
include <hello.h>;
include <bye.h>;
include <hola.h>;
...
```

Im using bindgen in rust to generate those file from c header to rust.
But I want to ignore generating the `include <hola.h>` header and generate the greeting.h only with `helllo.h` and `bye.h`.
I have searched it in docs.rs bindgen documentation but not found any hint on that.
or is there any option to do that with clang

Comment: In your `build.rs` file use _allowlisting_ or _blocklisting_ to specify for which parts of the library you want to generate bindings, more in [the docs](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-bindgen/customizing-generated-bindings.html).

Comment: @HHK thank you I figured it out with the allow list functionality

Comment: The *allowlisting* and *blocklisting* features are about halfway there for me. What I was really hoping for was to prohibit `bindgen` (and, really I guess it's `clang` underneath `bindgen`) from processing certain `#include`'d header files at all. I suppose that would probably mean altering the original C header files.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by guessing that my library that Im trying to bind from c to rust are "namespaced", in C language there is no actually namespaces but people that write open source code tend to prefix their code with "some_prefix*".
So if the h file that I want to bind looks like:

mylib.h:

```
include <hello.h>;
include <bye.h>;
include <hola.h>;
...

mylib_add_value(...);
mylib_remove_value(...);
mylib_display_value(...);
...
```

and I don't want the hola.h to be generated,
i can filter the output with allow and block functionality of bingden like:

build.rs:

```
fn main() {
    // Tell cargo to tell rustc to link the system nvpair of zfs
    // shared library.
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=mylib");

    // The bindgen::Builder is the main entry point
    // to bindgen, and lets you build up options for
    // the resulting bindings.
    let bindings = bindgen::Builder::default()
        // The input header we would like to generate
        // bindings for.
        .header("wrapper.h")
        .allowlist_var(r#"(\w*mylib\w*)"#)
        .allowlist_type(r#"(\w*mylib\w*)"#)
        .allowlist_function(r#"(\w*mylib\w*)"#)
        .blocklist_item(r#"(\w*hola\w*)"#)
        .blocklist_type(r#"(\w*hola\w*)"#)
        .blocklist_function(r#"(\w*hola\w*)"#)
        .clang_args(vec!["-I/usr/include/mylib"])
        .default_enum_style(bindgen::EnumVariation::Rust {
            non_exhaustive: (true),
        })
        // Finish the builder and generate the bindings.
        .generate()
        // Unwrap the Result and panic on failure.
        .expect("Unable to generate bindings");

    // Write the bindings to the $OUT_DIR/bindings.rs file.
    let out_path = PathBuf::from(env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap());
    bindings
        //.write_to_file(out_path)
        .write_to_file(out_path.join("bindings.rs"))
        .expect("Couldn't write bindings!");
}
```

Bindgen will bring all dependencies of allowlist firstly and if some of the dependencies include `*hola*` it won't generate it.